# Draggable gallery - out of viewport issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag

I'm working on little **photo gallery**.
Basically, what I want: a few photos (quantity should be dynamically adjustable!) inline-positioned, going out of the view of the window.
The page itself shouldn't be scrollable, however you can "scroll" through the images by simply **dragging** them.
Since I've worked with `.draggable` from the **jQuery UI** before and it worked surprisingly well and performant, I thought I'd just go ahead and use that.
Just making it draggable works perfectly fine.

**My problem:** I can move my gallery wherever I want: i can drag it outside the screen, i can just let go in the middle of the screen, etc.
I would prefer not being able to drag my content out of the viewport. ([here's](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/DraggableImageBoxesGrid) an example where it works. It wasn't made with .draggable though, but with bare JS).

HTML:

```
<div id="imgWrap">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imgWrap {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
}

#imgWrap img {
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

JS:

```
$("#imgWrap").draggable({
    axis: "x"
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x94Lxrdu/8

(I tried both the "containment" and "snap" function that .draggable offers, but neither of them worked.)

Thank you guys a lot in advance! Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to set the containment property:

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/x94Lxrdu/12/)***

```
var $imgWrap = $("#imgWrap");
$imgWrap.draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment : [window.innerWidth-$imgWrap.width(), 0,0,0]
});
```

The values inside `containment` represent: `[X1, Y1, X2, Y2]`

If you *don't want* to use `cotnainment` but add some **kinetic** and **animation**:
 ***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/x94Lxrdu/13/)***

Comment: wow, thank you so much! sounds so plausible. works like a champ!

Answer (score 1):

Use drag event to control boundaries, it's the simplest way I think.

Here is a demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/x94Lxrdu/11/)

Consider @Roko C. Buljan advice in comments to deal with window resije and images dynamic upload you better to have our right boundary inside drag function:

```
var images = document.getElementById('imgWrap');
var leftBoundary = 5; //5px for nice margin

$("#imgWrap").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        var rightBoundary = window.innerWidth - images.clientWidth - 5; //right boundary
        if (ui.position.left > leftBoundary) ui.position.left = leftBoundary;
        else if (ui.position.left < rightBoundary) ui.position.left = rightBoundary;
    }
});
```

And [a little bonus with kind of animation](http://jsfiddle.net/elennaro/x94Lxrdu/10/)

Comment: you should enclose the `rightBoundary` *returned value* from a function, so on a window resize the code won't break but hold the new value.

Comment: :D just have no time to write with frames animation. So forget it :)

Comment: works like a champ! thank you so much! i'll chose Roko C.'s answer though, since it's shorter. thanks!

Comment: I've voted for Roko's ansver, because its more correct way to do what you want. So you did the right thing! Good luck!